# writing pointer contents without copy

Tags: c++, performance, pointers

I'm trying to print N characters pointed to by a pointer, there is no terminating character. Lets just say I have something like this (hopefully my ascii artwork is ok here.. I want to write the chars/string "bcd" to file/stdout )

```
char* ptr ----> 'a' , 'b' , 'c' , 'd' , 'e' , 'f'

                    ^           ^      
                    |           |
                  begin        end
```

Now I have no terminating character there. I have a pointer to beginning and end of the chars I want to write to stdout (or a logfile say). Performance is really important say and I want to avoid the overhead of copy constructing std::string  (using the begin/end pointers).

Whats the *fastest* way to accomplish this, can anybody tell me? I've googled around but can't see anything. I could iterate over begin->end and print/write each char at a time but I'd like to get something faster/ready made. This is a theoretical question (for my own benefit) but I'd like to know how this is done in high performance applications (think FIX message strings in low latency applications).

Thanks much

Graham

Comment: Perhaps use [`std::string_view`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) instead of `std::string`? Also note that no matter how fast your code is, the big bottleneck is writing to the console. No matter if you use the C functions to write to `stdout`, or formatted C++ stream output to `std::cout`, that will make your own impact almost negligible.

Comment: Iostreams: `std::ostream::write`. Cstdio: `fwrite`. Though the biggest bottleneck will always be the actual writing (at the OS level).

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to make custom buffering I could suggest on something like this

```
class buffered_stream_buf : public std::streambuf {
public:
  buffered_stream_buf(std::ostream* stream)
    : _size(), _stream(stream), _out(_stream->rdbuf()) {
    _stream->rdbuf(this);
  }

  ~buffered_stream_buf() {
    _stream->flush();
    _stream->rdbuf(_out);
  }

  int sync() override {
    if (_size) {
      _out->sputn(_buffer, _size);
      _size = 0;
    }
    return _out->pubsync();
  }

  int overflow(int c) override {
    if (c == std::streambuf::traits_type::eof()) {
      return !std::streambuf::traits_type::eof();
    }
    _buffer[_size] = static_cast<char>(c);
    ++_size;
    if (_size == sizeof(_buffer) && sync() != 0)
      return std::streambuf::traits_type::eof();
    return c;
  }

private:
  char _buffer[8 * 1024];
  size_t _size;
  std::ostream* _stream;
  std::streambuf* _out;
};

int main() {
  // Unbuffering `cout` might be a good idea:
  // to avoid double copying
  std::cout.setf(std::ios::unitbuf);

  buffered_stream_buf mycoutbuf(&std::cout);
  std::ofstream f("testmybuffer.txt", std::ios_base::out);
  buffered_stream_buf myfbuf(&f);
  std::cout << "Hello";
  f << "Hello";

  std::string my_long_string("long_long_long");
  auto b = my_long_string.begin() + 3;
  auto e = my_long_string.begin() + 5;
  for (; b != e; ++b) {
    std::cout << *b;
    f << *b;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The question will this improve the performance? I am not sure, it can even worsen your performance. Why? `cout` and `fstream` are usually already buffered with a probably good size according to your machine. That means before being send to OS objects (files, pipes, etc) C++ std implementaion might buffer it (though it is not required by the standard). Adding new layer of buffering might not be unnecessary and hit the performance (you first copy it to your buffer, then later you copy it again to std buffer). Second, OS objects files, pipes are already mapped to memory, i.e. buffered. However, with this language buffering you achieve less system calls that might be expensive. To be sure if your own buffering is helpful you should benchmark it. You do not have time for that I recommend leaving it out of your scope and rely on std and OS, those are usually quite good in this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [std::basic_ostream::write](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write):

```
std::cout.write(begin, end - begin);
```

Comment: I suspect you need `end - begin + 1` since OP's end pointer is for some reason not one-past-the-end.